# Sound speaker like in game engines

Tags: audio

I want to have a speaker playing a sound in 3D space that behaves like a speaker in a game engine. When you place a speaker in UE or Unity, it can play a sound which you’ll hear louder as you approach it with your character, camera view etc. In Blender, it doesn’t seem to work so smooth. I expected that the sound would be played while animation is running, and I would hear louder or quieter sound as I move the view or camera around the speaker, but that doesn’t happen. Instead, I hear glitchy sound, getting sped up, doubled frequency or played backwards…
It is even possible to achieve that 3D space “distance-wise” sound source that will be played, preferably in a loop, in animation or just in the viewport, as I navigate?
I don’t consider the old BGE, just the new Blender 3.X versions.

Comment: Just to be clear.. can we can take it as read that the Speaker object settings and audio cache are not working for you? Or, do you need to clarify those?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Because I don't quite understand your question. What is Audio Cache, how does it work, and how do I know whether it's working or not?
First, I want to know if it's even possible to achieve what I had described.
There is that "Cache the sound in memory" setting at import, but I don't know if it should affect the result.

Comment: I ALMOST got it to work. When I'm playing animation in viewport and stay in camera view, the sound does get louder and quieter as I navigate closer and further to the speaker, but it's still glitchy. I guess that could be due to Doppler effect, but I'm not moving very fast and my scene has only sever meters across. The sound is restored to proper playback when I hit Update Animation Cache in Scene Properties, but I want to know if it's possible to make it work "on the fly", so I'd be moving camera and the sound volume would be automatically adjusted, without glitches and need to update cache.

Comment: Is the speaker's audio synced to F-curves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that works.  **Add a driver** based on the **distance** variable of the camera and your speaker to set the volume of your sound clip.

You add a sound strip to the sequencer, your music clip.
[image]

You select your sound strip and press n to go to the side bar.  Then go to the volume property and right click to add a driver.
[image]

You must then edit the driver.  Specify the two objects, your camera and the sound emitting object,  and switch the variable to "distance".
Divide the variable by 1 or another number so that the volume change is what is appropriate for your animation.

[image]

[image]

Now, by moving the camera towards the sound object, you get an increase in volume.

Comment: Yep, this works!

Comment: Sorry for late response. It initially seemed too complicated to me and took me a good hour of staring at your answer and googling drivers, as I've never used them before, but now it no longer appears difficult. Thanks a lot!